# Does apache ignite-web 2.15.0 works in Tomcat 10.1?

Tags: ignite, tomcat10, jakarta-migration

The apache ignite-web.jar: 2.15.0 still depends on javax.servlet which does not work in Tomcat 10.1 as it bundles the jakarta.servlet namespace.

Can you please let me how to make run apache ignite in Tomcat 10.1 web contianer ?

No clue till now on how to proceed.

Comment: I suppose that support of modern Servlet specs was not added to ignite yet. Ignite web module (https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/web/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite) is quite small, so I guess that you can take it as a basis and adopt to desired servlet spec. If you decide to do this, Ignite community will appreciate if you contribute this fixes back later.